# Creating an API for a website

Tags: javascript, api

Hello guys I am new to http and I have the following code

```
var htpquest = new XMLHttpRequest();
htpquest.open("GET", "http://www.herbiesheadshop.com/", false);
htpquest.send();
```

but I seem to get a 101 error when trying to connect to the website. I not sure if the website doesn't have xml or JSON, but the main purpose of this would be to try and get a connection, and from that I would use JavaScript to sort out different items they sell. Pretty much compare them. If any one could point me in the right direction much would be appreciated. Thank you, caleb

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a cross-domain request which are generally not allowed unless otherwise specified. Thus, you are getting an error.

Comment: Is there ways around this?

Answer (score 0):

For one, you've encountered the [same origin policy](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) limitation. You cannot establish a connection with a random website, as this represents a security issue. You can make requests only to the website hosting the JavaScript file itself.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies, yet im still not sure where to go with this. I read the link and it said to work around this to use JSONP and AJAX? Would that be able to solve my problem?

Comment: It depends on what is it that you're actually trying to achieve, but I guess you should be looking at cross-origin resource sharing instead http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing